# Where to put sql file in spring boot app for it to generate H2 database

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, h2

It is not clear where to put the SQL file in order for my H2 database to be initialized.

in my `application-h2.properties` file I have:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;Mode=Oracle
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.profiles.active=h2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

My SQL file is pure oracle SQL generated from sqlDeveloper. I tried to cut and paste it in the H2 console but it didn't accept it. I am hoping this way will work.

------------------------update 1---------------------------

schema.sql

```
schema.sql]: CREATE SEQUENCE "foo"."ADDRESSID_SEQ" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE SEQUENCE ""foo"".""ADDRESSID_SEQ"" MINVALUE[*] 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"; SQL statement:
```

data.sql

```
data.sql]: CREATE SEQUENCE "foo"."ADDRESSID_SEQ" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE SEQUENCE ""foo"".""ADDRESSID_SEQ"" MINVALUE[*] 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"; SQL statement:
CREATE SEQUENCE "foo"."ADDRESSID_SEQ" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE [42000-148]
```

Error

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #3
```

This is the same sql file, I just renamed it. It has creates and inserts. However if I name it `schema.sql` or `data.sql` it still fails on the third line. It doesn't appear to fail when creating a user or schema.

------------------Update 2----------------

```
 CREATE USER foo ifentified by foo;

  CREATE SCHEMA foo;

  CREATE TABLE foo.ADDRESS
   (ADDRESS_ID NUMBER(22,0),
    CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(*,0),
    COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    ADDITIONAL_ADDRESS_INFO VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    STREET VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    ADDITIONAL_STREET_INFO VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    HOUSE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    ZIP VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    CITY VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    STATE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    COUNTRY_CODE CHAR(2 BYTE),
    PHONE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    MODIFIED_AT TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    VALIDATED_AT TIMESTAMP (6),
    VALIDATION_RESULT VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING


   COMMENT ON COLUMN foo.ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID IS 'primary key for table address';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN foo.ADDRESS.CUSTOMER_ID IS 'foreign key for table customer';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN foo.ADDRESS.CREATED_AT IS 'initially created at';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN foo.ADDRESS.MODIFIED_AT IS 'date of last modification';
```

Error

`Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE FOO.ADDRESS (ADDRESS_ID NUMBER(22,0), CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(*[*],0), COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), ADDITIONAL_ADDRESS_INFO VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), STREET VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), ADDITIONAL_STREET_INFO VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), HOUSE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), ZIP VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), CITY VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), STATE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), COUNTRY_CODE CHAR(2 BYTE), PHONE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MODIFIED_AT TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, VALIDATED_AT TIMESTAMP (6), VALIDATION_RESULT VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING COMMENT ON COLUMN FOO.ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID IS 'primary key for table address' "; expected "long"; SQL statement`:

Answer (score 0):

You should name the file `data.sql` and save it in *src/main/resources* folder. In this location the file will be detected and executed automatically. This, in the case that you want to leave default schema generation (as defined by your `@Entity` annotated classes).

If you want to generate also the schema manually you can create the file `schema.sql` where you put all the details for creating the schema.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Please see update one. I am almost there.

Comment: In a oracle database yes it works. I tried them against oracle db docker container.

Comment: Yes, the quotes may be a problem, try removing them.

Comment: I removed the quotes with no avail.

Comment: Wish there was a way I could generate MYSQL from a oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

edited answer after update 2.

you cannot use "

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "foo"."ADDRESSID_SEQ" ...
```

so try instead (foo is the schema-name)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo.ADDRESSID_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE CACHE 20;
```

do'nt known if you can use `NOORDER`

use `BIGINT` instead of `NUMBER(...)` see `...expected "long"...` in error.

Comment: I took out the sequence statements but will put them back. Please see update 2 and thank you for thanks the time to post.

Comment: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE SEQUENCE foo-[*]ADDRESSID_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"; SQL statement:
CREATE SEQUENCE foo-ADDRESSID_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE [42000-148]`

Comment: Wish there was a way I could generate MYSQL from a oracle DB

Comment: updated answer: was a typo, `-` char cannot be used... and you cannot use *

Comment: I removed `*` and all the quotes. It just keeps failing. They're also some case where `TABLESPACE foo;`  is used at the end of some inserts. I tried your suggestion with and without `CREATE SEQUENCE ` The error says `CREATE SEQUENCE foo_ADDRESSID_SEQ MINVALUE[*] ` but there is not a `*` in the statement. `CREATE SEQUENCE  foo_ADDRESSID_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE;` When I remove the `create sequence` statements the insets fail. Only thing that seems to work is creating a user and schema.

Answer (score 0):

You should place .sql file inside the resource folder, so that H2 database will be initialized as per your requirement